# CORS issue in IdentityServer 4

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, cors, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer 4 as oauth for my application ( Reactjs ) I'm running Identityserver on port http://localhost:5000 and reactjs app on http://localhost:3000. I have tried using CORS for my idenityserver4 with the following code.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
   
        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        })
            
            .AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
            //.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddResourceStore<ResourceStore>()
            //.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddCustomUserStore()
           .AddCertificateFromFile();

        
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins( "http://localhost:3000/")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });


    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        
        
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        //app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        // uncomment, if you want to add an MVC-based UI
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

Even though I have added localhost:3000 in WithOrigins(), when I try to make a request from react app with axios I'm getting the following blocked error.
[image]

Can someone help me to know where I'm doing wrong. I need my application to only allow some list of origins (apps)
Thanks

Comment: Can you post whole Startup.cs because order of middlewares is also important?

Comment: try use only AllowAnyOrigin() without WithOrigins( "http://localhost:3000/")

Comment: @zhuber I have updated the code you can see the order now

Comment: @foadabd I wanted only localhost:3000 to access the identityserver so AllowAnyOrigin() won't work for me.

Comment: @p.durgashankar ok try use only WithOrigins( "localhost:3000/")  without  AllowAnyOrigin() and maybe need AllowCredentials()

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, the reason here is trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely this could be because of the trailing slash, this is mentioned in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware).

> Note: The specified URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the URL terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is returned.

Try `http://localhost:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000/`.

I'd also question the usage of both `.AllowAnyOrigin()` and `.WithOrigins()`.  What you're looking to achieve should be possible using only `.WithOrigins()`.

Comment: after removing trailing slash It is working :) Thanks you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending a request to another domain, try sending a http request from your identity server not react.js app. I encountered a similar issue but i just used my API as a proxy and it worked fine.